# Sending a request using fetch in Javascript for a partial/ajax request

Tags: javascript, node.js, partial-response

What I am trying to do is to get a request from a server using fetch in Javascript.
The problem is that the answer is coming like a partial-response with xml, so the answer don't come at once, but fetch only give me the first part.

I already tried things like asynchronous things (like await, or then), but I always have only the first part of the answer.

Here is my code :

```js
let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: // my body
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Connection': 'close',
            'Faces-Request': 'partial/ajax',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            // then cookie, user-agent ...
        }});
```

I also tried using XMLHttpRequest, but I need to use a Cookie header, that I can't use with it.

For the answer, I am expecting something like this (I replaced the personal informations with _) :

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="form:messages">
            <![CDATA[_]]></update>
        <update id="form:j_idt117">
            <![CDATA[_]]></update>
        <update id="form:j_idt133">
            <![CDATA[_]]></update>
        <update id="form:j_idt228">
            <![CDATA[_]]></update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[_]]></update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

But I get :

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="form:j_idt228">
            <![CDATA[_]]></update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[_]]></update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

So the question is, does fetch have something to help me with it ? I thought first of a wait before beginning to hear for the answer, but I find no documentation on that kind of thing.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You need to check this in your backend. What happen when you send the request with postman or other similar tools?

Comment: I don't think Fetch can set the cookie header, either, for the same security reason as XHR. If you want to set a cookie you have to assign `document.cookie`. Then use the `credentials:` option so that Fetch will send cookies.

Comment: Using burp, I get the XML part that is shown in the XML which is expecting.

Comment: I tried ading "credentials: 'include'", but I still have the same answer. But I don't think that the problem come from the cookie, as in this case, the cookie is used for some kind of authentification, but it is still giving me the good status code with an answer, just not all the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code - `node-fetch`:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function fetchChunked(url, options) {
  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch ${url}: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  const chunks = [];
  let length = 0;
  for await (const chunk of response.body) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
    length += chunk.length;
  }

  const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks, length);
  const data = buffer.toString('utf-8');
  return data;
}

const url = 'https://example.com';
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: // my body
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Connection': 'close',
    'Faces-Request': 'partial/ajax',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    // then cookie, user-agent ...
  },
};

const data = await fetchChunked(url, options);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: When doing this, I have an error "TypeError: response.body.getReader is not a function", am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I updated the code with:
  let responseClone = response.clone();
  let reader = responseClone.body.getReader();

Can you try, please?

If this is code from node.js, not the browser it may require some changes. Are you using node-fetch?

Comment: Yes I am using fetch from le node-fetch library. I tried using the updated code, but still the same, "responseClone.body.getReader is not a function".

Comment: Trying to figure out if simple await response.text() will do the trick, I expect your incorrect result is coming through this, right? I update the code in the answer.

Comment: I tried this, as in your code update, I obtain as result "<partial-response id="j_id1"><error><error-name>class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[Index: 0, Size: 0]]></error-message></error></partial-response>"
I tried to your update with axios and get an error "response.data.on is not a function", don't really know why 

Comment: Let's keep on trying, I updated my answer, try this

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is running, but I still have the same response as in my initial question, which is incomplete. I think I am missing something. I tried too using the same process but using python and I also have the same incomplete answer, but if I put the same request in Burp, I get the complete answer.